# MYSQL: заполнение таблицы с id

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица feedback:

`id | authorid  |  subject  |  text`

Хочу заполнять ее так:

```
INSERT INTO feedback SET id=id+1,authorid=1,subject=2,text=3
```

1. Почему оно не работает? `id = id + 1` всегда возвращает 1.
2. Если таблица пустая `id = id + 1` вернет NULL и таблица не заполнится. Как решить данную проблему?

Буду очень рад за полный запрос. Заранее спасибо.

PS: анологичную проблему описали [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587562/problem-with-mysql-insert-max1), но мне нужно без `where=bob`, пытался сам составить, не получалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Илюшка Овчинников, а попробуй вот так

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO feedback(id, authorid, subject, text) SELECT(SELECT MAX(id)+1 from feedback), 1, 'subject_text', 'blablabla'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

у меня все отлично получилось и id увеличивается на 1

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE `feedback` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Я бы сказал, это решит вашу проблему.

По вопросам:
id = id + 1 всегда возвращает 1.// Все просто. Создается строка. Id, как инту, присваивается значение 0. 0+1 = 1. Естественно, если ID NOT NULL.

Если таблица пустая.....Как решить данную проблему?// написать условие:

```
IF((select max(`id`) as `mid` from `feedback` where 1),id=mid+1,id=1)
```

Но это извращение. Ужасное извращение. Используйте автоинкремент. Выше показано как он подключается к пустой таблице.

Comment: какую именно проблему?

Answer (score 1):

А кто отменил автоинкремент в MySQL? Или нужно вручную следить за ид?

**Добавлено.**

```
ALTER TABLE `feedback` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Вот по ссылке без боба

```
INSERT INTO users (id, authorid,subject,text) 
SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(user_id) FROM users ), 0), 1,2,3;
```

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: Вручную.

Comment: тогда coalesce((SELECT max(user_id) FROM users ), 0) этот запрос считает макс ид, а это SELECT 1 + делает как у вас id=id+1.

Comment: огромное спасибо за ответ

Comment: зачем FROM users ? у него пади такой и таблицы то нет! не запутывайте чела еще больше

Answer (score 0):

При каждой вставке id наращивалась сама на еденицу

Answer (score 0):

Используйте AUTO_INCREMENT в поле id и будет вам ЩаЗтЬе!